# style sheet problem

Tags: three20

I wrote code like:

```
+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)item {
    CustomTTTableSubtitleItem* captionedItem = item;
    CGFloat maxWidth = tableView.width - kHPadding*2;
    CGSize titleSize = [captionedItem.title sizeWithFont:TTSTYLEVAR(myTitleFont) constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
}
```

Got this exception:

> 2011-07-24 03:10:18.762 xinyou[15941:b303] -[TTDefaultStyleSheet
>   myTitleFont]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b5e120
>   2011-07-24 03:10:18.765 xinyou[15941:b303] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[TTDefaultStyleSheet myTitleFont]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x5b5e120'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x0119a5a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x012ee313 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0119c0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x0110b966 __*forwarding*** + 966
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x0110b522
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50    5   xinyou
>   0x000081f9 +[CustomTTTableSubtitleItemCell
>   tableView:rowHeightForObject:] + 186  6   xinyou
>   0x000a6c92 -[TTTableViewVarHeightDelegate
>   tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] + 156     7   UIKit
>   0x0064a6d5 -[UISectionRowData

In this exception you can see `[TTDefaultStyleSheet myTitleFont]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b5e120` but actually `myTitleFont` defined in `XYDefaultStyleSheet` and I've imported `XYDefaultStyleSheet.h` in my class. `XYDefaultStyleSheet.h` and `XYDefaultStyleSheet.m` are like:

`XYDefaultStyleSheet.h`

```
#import "Three20/Three20.h"

@interface XYDefaultStyleSheet : TTDefaultStyleSheet

@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIColor* myHeadingColor;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIColor* mySubtextColor;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIColor* myTitleColor;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIFont* myTitleFont;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIFont* myHeadingFont;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIFont* mySubtextFont;


@end
```

XYDefaultStyleSheet.m

```
#import "XYDefaultStyleSheet.h"


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@implementation XYDefaultStyleSheet


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// styles

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// public colors

- (UIColor*)myTitleColor {
    return [UIColor blackColor];
}

- (UIColor*)myHeadingColor {
    return RGBCOLOR(80, 110, 140);
}

- (UIColor*)mySubtextColor {
    return [UIColor grayColor];
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// public fonts

- (UIFont*)myTitleFont {
    return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
}

- (UIFont*)myHeadingFont {
    return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
}

- (UIFont*)mySubtextFont {
    return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
}


@end
```

why always tell `[TTDefaultStyleSheet myTitleFont]` ... if the problem is really `myTitleFont`, it should be `[XYDefaultStyleSheet myTitleFont]`, why `TTDefaultStyleSheet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to @Jason Zhao's answer about initialising within the `AppDelegate`.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {      
    // Override point for customization after app launch   
    [TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:[[[CustomDefaultStyleSheet alloc]  
                                        init] autorelease]];  

    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];  
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];  
}
```

Original code is from here, which has a lot of useful information about using `TTStyleSheet`'s:

[Three20 Stylesheets iPhone Tutorial](http://mattvague.com/three20-stylesheets-tutorial)

Comment: No worries @Jason Zhao. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

got it! Init my style sheet in AppDelegate.